# Validate list of dependent values after parent value changes

Tags: angularjs

Using Angular 1.5+

This is my scenario... I've got one base field, call it 'base'.
Then I've got a list of fields that need to be multiples of that base and I'm using a $validator for that... a simple modulus check.

I can validate each individual field... so if I highlight a field in the list and change it's value, it will fire and validate properly.

What I need is to be able to change the 'base' value and re-evaluate all the children. I've looked at a ton of slightly different angular questions that are similar, but none that seem to help me in this particular case.

So a view like this:

```
<div ng-controller="myAppController as app" >
  <input type="text" ng-model="app.base" >
  <br><br>
  are these multiples of above?
  <br><br>
  <div ng-repeat="v in app.values">
    <input type="text" ng-model="v.value" multiple-of="{{app.base}}" />
 </div>
```

app and controller like this:

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('myAppController', function myAppController($filter) {
    var self = this;
    self.base = 10;
    self.values = [
      {value: 10},
      {value: 20},
      {value: 30},
      {value: 40},
      {value: 50}];
  });
```

With a validator like this for the list of values:

```
  app.directive('multipleOf', function () {
      return {
          require: 'ngModel',
          link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ngModel) {
              ngModel.$validators.multipleOf = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
                  var value = parseInt(modelValue);
                  var base =  parseInt(attrs.multipleOf);
                  var valid = value >= base && value % base === 0;
                  return valid;
              };
          }
      };
  });
```

In this particular setup, if I change base to 20, the list values of 20 and 40 should validate, but now the other three should be invalid. How can I trigger this cascading validation when the base value changes?

Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/dcc4XFyrPAyLUpT38Dbe?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution...

First, rather than evaluating the base expression in the view, just pass in the property as a string

```
<div ng-controller="myAppController as app" >
  <input type="text" ng-model="app.base" >
  <br><br>
  are these multiples of above?
  <br><br>
  <div ng-repeat="v in app.values">
    <input type="text" ng-model="v.value" multiple-of="app.base" />
</div>
```

That allows us to put a $watch on the property we depend on, and we can just use scope.$eval to get the model's value when the validator fires:

```
  app.directive('multipleOf', function() {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ngModel) {
        ngModel.$validators.multipleOf = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
            var value = parseInt(modelValue);
            var base = parseInt(scope.$eval(attrs.multipleOf));
            var valid = value >= base && value % base === 0;
            return valid;
        };
        scope.$watch(attrs.multipleOf, function() {
          ngModel.$validate();
        })
      }
    };
  });
```

Revised plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/9FBhaINpsXW3GxuBgi3E?p=preview

Comment: You are aware that the $eval with the input of an inputfiels is a big security risk. Everything you put in will be executed also javascript code.

Comment: It's not executing $eval on the field value itself... it's using $eval to get the value of the property. It's basically saying 'Get me the value of app.base'...this is safe.

Comment: This makes the directive more useable. But still find it a short turn that doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 1):

I have edited your plunker to make it work: https://plnkr.co/edit/LW3rRmFSmCdnLUMdqr7Z?p=preview

It's not the best code that I wrote but it will explain the basics because now the directive is not reusable as it should be intended;

```
app.directive('multipleOf', function() {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ngModel) {
        scope.myForm.base.$viewChangeListeners.push(function() {
          scope.myForm.value10.$validate();
          scope.myForm.value20.$validate();
          scope.myForm.value30.$validate();
          scope.myForm.value40.$validate();
          scope.myForm.value50.$validate();
        });
        ngModel.$validators.multipleOf = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
          if (scope.myForm.base.$modelValue && scope.myForm.base.$modelValue >= 0) {
            var value = modelValue || 0;
            var base = parseInt(scope.myForm.base.$modelValue);
            var valid = value >= base && value % base === 0;
            return valid;
          }
        };
      }
    };
  });
```

But if you want other fields to validate after one is changed you need to add $viewChangeListeners. I hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your response... it got me somewhat in the right direction, but I found a more elegant solution which I posted.

Comment: The elegance is debatable.